# inputing a text file that has a list of planets and information on them and searching them in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm very new to perl, and still trying to get used to it. so ive been practicing and I found this project online, and ive been trying to figure it out, but I'm stuck.
these are the instuctions:

```
Print all records that do not list a discoverer in the eighth field.  
This file contains lines of 9 items, the first being: 
Adrastea XV Jupiter 129000 0.30 0.00 0.00 Jewitt 1979 in alphabetical order by the name of the planet or moon (first field). The text in [] is the corresponding field from the line above. 

The fields in this file are:
1. Name of planet or moon [Adrastea]
2. Number of moon or planet (roman numerals) [XV]
3. Name of the abject around which the satellite orbits [Jupiter]
4. Orbital radius (semimajor axis) in kilometers [129000]
5. Orbital period in days [0.30]
6. Orbital inclination in degrees [0.00]
7. Orbital eccentricity [0.00]
8. Discoverer [Jewitt]
9. Year of discovery [1979]
```

This is an example of a line from my data that I want to print (i.e. where there is no discoverer named):

```
Earth III Sun 149600000 365.26 0.00 0.02 - - # Discoverer not named -> print
```

I'm stuck on how to search the file and finding which rows don't have a discoverer listed.

This is my code so far (I'm sure that my last if statement is wrong):

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my $filename = 'solar.txt';
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF -8)', $filename)
        or die "could not open file!!!";
            #print "$fh";

    while ( my $row = <$fh>) {
         my ( $planet, 
              $number_moons, 
              $obj_orbit, 
              $orbital_radius, 
              $orbital_period, 
              $orbital_inclination, 
              $orbtial_eccentricity, 
              $discoverer, 
              $year
         ) = split / /, $row;

         if( $row !~ $discoverer ){
             print "$row";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You probably want to use a regular expression here, not split due to the lines being delimited by whitespace. If there is no discoverer listed, then the `$discoverer` scalar will be filled in with the value of what would have gone into `$year`.

Comment: my question is to find the rows on the list that do not have a discoverer and print them. but I cant seem to get any further that what I have up top.

Comment: Hunter McMillen, I'm sorry I do not understand what you are trying to say exactly. Sorry very new to this language.

Comment: try `print "$row\n" if $discoverer eq '-'`

Comment: yes, fugu that worked. I dint realize that all the blank ones had a '-' or the other ones had a '?'. thanks a bunch. I definitely need to keep my eyes open to those little details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled and found your data and you're almost there. However, you should include an example of a line that you want to print in your question, such as:

```
Adrastea XV Jupiter 129000 0.30 0.00 0.00 Jewitt 1979 # Discoverer named -> don't print
Earth III Sun 149600000 365.26 0.00 0.02 - - # Discoverer not named -> print
```

This makes it easier to diagnose the problem in your code. Try this `if` statement:

```
if ($discoverer eq '-'){
    print "$row\n";
}
```

Comment: hey fugu or anyone else that can help. I have encountered another problem. I need to remove the second element of every line(the period, which are the roman numerals). I set everything into an array but for some reason it only removes the second element from the first line. do you have any ideas on what could work?? here is the code that I got so far:#!/usr/bin/perl
open(DICT, "<solar.txt");

 while (@line = <DICT>) { # Loop through each line
   $moons = "@line";
   @line = split(/ /, $moons); 
     
   splice(@lines, 1 , 1 , " ");

   print "@line\n"; # print out the words…
 
}
 close(DICT);

Comment: @johncastello - You should ask another question. However a quick glance at your code suggests that the problem could be fixed by replacing `while (@line = <DICT>)` with `while ($line = <DICT>)`